# AngularJS checkbox filter true and false

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a checkbox `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="search.isWorking" />`
And after click on it I have filtered list with only true value, and it's Ok :)
But if I uncheked I want list with all vale (true and false) but angular give me only false value. How can I do that ?

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you post your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh, stackoverflow cut my code ;)
SOLVED: I do that:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="search.isWorking" ng-click="onClick(search.isWorking)" />

 $scope.onClick = function ($event) {
                    if($event === false)
                    {
                        $scope.search.isWorking = "";
                    }
                }
```

After that i have a list without filtering in false value.